# Using React Native Hooks

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to get to learn hooks and react native in general.

Currently I'm trying to create a small shopping list app, where you'd add your desired item to the list.

I already have the input + button on the display.

```
<View>
    <TextInput placeholder="hinzufügen..." 
         onChangeText={inputHandler} 
         value={enteredEntity} 
     />

     <Button title="+" onPress={addInputHandler} />
</View>
```

I have two functions + hook declared as the following:

```
const [enteredEntity, setEnteredEntity] = useState('');

const inputHandler = (enteredEntity) => {
    setEnteredEntity(enteredEntity);
}

const addInputHandler = () => {
    console.log(enteredEntity);
}
```

and get the following error message (see below) - at Line 20, where the error should be I have the TextInput.

[image]

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Please show the entire code. Did you imported useState? `import React, { useState } from 'react'`

Comment: Thank you Ian, this solved the issue for me. I was totally missing the import.

Comment: import React, {useState}  from 'react'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian suggested in his comment, the issue was due to the missing import of `{ useState }`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how hooks can be implemented. This example implemented with componentDidUpdate. Depending on the second argument of useEffect this hook can act as componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate. useEffect runs every render is done, that could cause infinite loop so always try to pass 2nd argument

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect}  from 'react';

    const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(session.userBalance);
    useEffect(()=>{
                setUserBalance(session.userBalance)
            },[session.userBalance]);
```

Answer (score 0):

import React, {useState}  from 'react'